# Ajax POST returns undefined error from a ashx page

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, ashx

I keep receiving the undefined error. Here is the ajax method.

```
function testing() {
    var data = JSON.stringify(
        {
            "TestID1": "12345",
            "TestID2": "12345",
            "TestID3": "12345",
        });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Test.ashx",
        data: data,
        //async: false,
        //cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.ID);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.status);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the controller/handler.

```
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string jsonString = String.Empty;
            HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            using (StreamReader inputStream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
            {
                jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
                JavaScriptSerializer jSerialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var receipt = jSerialize.Deserialize<Receipt>(jsonString);

                if (receipt != null)
                {
                    InsertData(receipt.TestID1, receipt.TestID1, receipt.TestID1);
                    var wrapper = new { ID = receipt.TestID1};
                    context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrapper));
                    //context.Response.Write("{ \"data\": [1,2,3] }");
                    //context.Response.End();
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Right now I am getting undefined error, but I was getting the "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" until recently. The data that is being posted is working since the InsertData() function inserts the correct data. I also tried setting the async function in the ajax method to false, but no luck. Also, tried sending specific responses (like the one commented out) and so far none have succeeded.

Comment: "undefined error" - there is no such error, can you please go back and get the actual error message

Comment: When I use the "alert(errorThrown)" all that comes back is "undefined". And when I open the firefox debugging tool under the XHR POST method it just says "Undefined". If neither of those are the correct error then how do you get the correct one?

Comment: well, if there's an error it would probably be in the browser console.  Do you get three alerts (the error path) or one (the success path)?  Maybe response.ID is just undefined and theres no actual error.  Check the Network tab of your browser devtools, find the XHR request, and look at what you send/receive back, make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: So the error I am now getting again is the "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". Also, in the XHR request there is no response.